# How to save many items on one form rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to save many items to Cart on form, user enter quantity one form, and selected items goes to db, but now save only first entered quantity of item. Why?

my form

```
<%= form_for @cart_item do |f| %>
<% @category.items.each do |item| %>
<%= item.name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :item_id, :value => item.id %>

<%= f.text_field :qty %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And controller
cart_items_controller.rb

```
class CartItemsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]


    def create
        @cart_items = CartItem.create(cart_items_params)
        @cart_items.cart_id = @cart.id
        if @cart_items.save
        redirect_to :back
        else
            render root_path
        end
    end

    private

    def cart_items_params
        params.require(:cart_item).permit(:id, :qty, :item_id, :cart_id)
    end

    def set_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        @cart = Cart.create
        session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this:

```
def create
        @cart_items = params[:cart_items]
        @cart_items.each do |c|
            @cart_item = CartItem.new(c)
            if @cart_item.qty.present?
                @cart_item.cart_id = @cart.id
                @cart_item.save
            end
        end
```

and form

```
<%= form_tag cart_items_path do %>
<% @cart_items.each do |cart_item| %>
<%= fields_for "cart_items[]", cart_item do |f| %>
    <% @category.items.each do |item| %>
      <%= item.name %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
      <%= f.text_field :qty %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here. I'll give you a little bump:

```
<% @category.items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, :value => item.id %>

  <%= f.text_field :qty %>
<% end %>
```

For each `CartItem`, this is going to create an input like this

```
<input name="qty">
```

This is problematic because only one *(the last one in the DOM)* will be submitted. You need to research [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) and incorporate that into your loop in order to get unique names for each `Item` in the form.

This same issue follows through into your controller

```
def cart_items_params
  params.require(:cart_item).permit(:id, :qty, :item_id, :cart_id)
end
```

This is going to look for a single `:id`, `:qty`, `:item_id`, and `:cart_id`, when in reality you're looking to accept multiple `:item_id` and `:qty` fields. You need to research [Strong Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) with nested has_many associations.

Finally you have this

```
@cart_items = CartItem.create(cart_items_params)
```

which is going to attempt to create a single `CartItem` when you're really trying to create multiple items and associate them back to the `Cart`. You need to research [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) as well as more generally "rails form save `has_many` association". It's a **widely** covered topic here on SO and elsewhere.